# autosuggest showing blank li's

Tags: php, mysql, css

I am using [Paper Mashups Autosuggest.](http://papermashup.com/jquery-php-ajax-autosuggest/)

I just finished doing a mysql union to bring three tables into one so I could autosuggest names of companies, names of categories and names of subcategories. Unfortunately, while that worked, it added extra li's ( I think that's what they are, here's the  [picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rMRj.png))

How do I get rid of those extra li's?

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root' ,'*********', '****************');

if(!$db) {

    echo 'Could not connect to the database.';
} else {

    if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {
        $queryString = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);

        if(strlen($queryString) >0) {
            $query = $db->query("SELECT name FROM company WHERE name LIKE '$queryString%' UNION SELECT cat FROM cat WHERE cat LIKE '$queryString%' UNION SELECT subcat FROM subcat WHERE subcat LIKE '$queryString%' LIMIT 10");
            if($query) {
            echo '<ul>';
                while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
                    echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.addslashes($result->name).'\');">'.$result->name.'</li>';
                    echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.addslashes($result->cat).'\');">'.$result->cat.'</li>';
                    echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.addslashes($result->subcat).'\');">'.$result->cat.'</li>';
                }
            echo '</ul>';

            } else {
                echo 'OOPS we had a problem :(';
            }
        } else {
            // do nothing
        }
    } else {
        echo 'There should be no direct access to this script!';
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks for all help!

Comment: It appears `$result->name` is populating an <li> but the other two values are coming back empty...there-by resulting an empty <li> elements. You should do a `var_dump` of `$result` to make sure those values are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like it's spitting out blanks.  Try just using **name** first, then just **cat**, then just **subcat** to find the culprit.  Also, your subcat in your three echoes is echoeing cat instead of subcat...

```
echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.addslashes($result->subcat).'\');">'.$result->cat.'</li>';
```

Should be:

```
echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.addslashes($result->subcat).'\');">'.$result->subcat.'</li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put check :

```
while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
                if($result->name && $result->cat && $result->subcat){
                  echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.addslashes($result->name).'\');">'.$result->name.'</li>';
                  echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.addslashes($result->cat).'\');">'.$result->cat.'</li>';
                  echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.addslashes($result->subcat).'\');">'.$result->cat.'</li>';
                 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your query to look like the following, that would make it easier to understand and easier to manipulate:

```
SELECT name as SuggestText FROM company WHERE name LIKE '$queryString%' 
UNION 
SELECT cat as SuggestText FROM cat WHERE cat LIKE '$queryString%' 
UNION 
SELECT subcat as SuggestText FROM subcat WHERE subcat LIKE '$queryString%' LIMIT 10
```

and then you modify your loop to look like the following:

```
while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
     echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.addslashes($result->SuggestText).'\');">'.$result->SuggestText.'</li>';
}
```